# Homology of $S^n/G_x$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

I tried to find the homology groups of the quotient of the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ by an action of a finite subgroup $G$ of $SO(n)$. I'm especially concerned with
$$H_i(S^{n-1}/G),\quad 1\leq i\leq n-2.$$ 
I haven't found any reference for this problem.

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ acts freely on $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: No, the action need not to be free. $G<SO(n)$ acts on $R^n$ by linear transformations. It preserves the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: OK.  The situation for free actions is well understood, but I do not know of anything systematic than can be said for non-free actions.

Comment: What about the case of free action?